# Get default Billing/Shipping address of logged in customer Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento, frontend, magento2

This is my first project using Magento 2. I'm having a hard time getting the default billing/shipping address of the logged in customer to display at the frontend of my custom module.

So far I have this:

```
//this gets the billing id which is an integer. I'm thinking it must be loaded to get the whole data of the address
$billingId =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();

//just found this in the internet and thought it might be the same as loading an order, but it doesn't work
$address = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory')->load($billingId);
```

But the error says:
`Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory::load()`

I think I'm close but I don't know what to do next. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to get the billing address of logged in customer is :

```
$billingID =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
$address = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($billingID);
echo "<pre>";print_r($address->getData());exit;
```

Comment: Using object manager directly is not good habit.
What is more, here should be proper repository for address used.

Comment: Instead of pointing out the "wrong" way to do it and then just leave why not write a suggestion of how it's really suppsoed to be implemented.